# Is there a way to revoke ecr tokens before they expire (12 hours is the default lifetime of a token)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ecr

**Usecase:** Get ECR Authorization token --> Work with ECR (using this token) --> Revoke Token. Continue this cycle *on-demand*.

**Reason** To avoid leaving tokens (after use) for the default lifetime of 12 hours.

Have looked up AWS doco [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/Registries.html) and doco for [get-authorization-token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-authorization-token.html) and [available ecr commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/index.html#cli-aws-ecr) but coudln't find a way to revoke.

For instance, Docker Trusted Registry allows you to revoke access tokens anytime as documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/ee/dtr/user/access-tokens/)

Comment: The fact that it's not possible to revoke an ECR token seems like a massive security risk to me.

Comment: Have raised a feature request https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/936

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of December 2019, there is no way to do this.

Another feature the ECR team could add is the ability to specify a token lifetime that's shorter than 12 hours. This may be easier for some people to use than remembering to revoke a token after use.

I'd raise a feature request in their roadmap here: https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap.

Comment: yeah token lifetime definitely helps but my use case was specific to be able to revoke any active token on demand.